# How to enable Parallel Data WareHouse?

Tags: sql-server

How do I enable Parallel Data Warehouse on my Microsoft SQL Server. I am trying to run this SQL statement below and received this error.

ERROR:

```
Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.
```

CODE:

```
select A.gender, A.firstname, A.weight,
       SUM(a.weight) over (partition by a.gender
                           order by a.weight) as 'New Column'
 from ChildStat A
 order by a.gender, a.weight;
```

Comment: You don't "enable" PDW. PDW is a proprietary SQL Server version configured specifically for use with very (expensive) specialized data warehousing hardware. The error message is misleading, but the solution is to remove the ORDER BY from the OVER() clause. You're getting a SUM, which means the value will be the same for every row of that gender; what would ordering by weight there achieve?

Comment: Will probably nothing. I was just testing some queries that we had in some training a while back.